# Strange pixels drawn on QPixmap

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I notice that when I use a QPixmap inside a QLabel, seemingly random pixels (possibly based on memory) are written to the QPixmap. Why is this, and how can this be fixed? Is this just a problem with my computer? (I use Windows 7, by the way.)

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel

class BugTest(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setPixmap(QPixmap(200, 200))
        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = BugTest()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: `functools` may override a name that's imported elsewhere. PEP8 says that system library imports should go above all other imports. See if the same behavior occurs if you do that.

Comment: @aryamccarthy Nope, still has similar behavior... though I do notice less pixels are being drawn.

Comment: Using PyQt4, I still see pixels drawn when the functools import is commented out.  Are you sure none are drawn?  They seem to vary in position, and sometimes they are hard to see if they are right at the edge of the window.

Comment: Now that I really pay attention, I think the same thing's happening on PyQt5 as well. I guess I should change the question...

Comment: I suggest you include some code (after creating the widget but before execing the app) that prints nonzero pixel vales, e.g., `QColor(QImage(widget.pix).pixel(x, y)).getRgbF()` in a loop (and with an `if` to filter out values that are just `(0, 0, 0, 1)`).  That will let you see for sure if there are some pixels there with and without the import, rather than relying on visual inspection.  For me, with PyQt4, there are spurious pixels whether the import is there or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#QPixmap-2) says:

> Warning: This will create a QPixmap with uninitialized data.  Call fill() to fill the pixmap with an appropriate color before drawing onto it with QPainter.

That means it may contain junk.  If you want it to be all black, fill it with black.